# Rails model & controller naming semantics?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, naming-conventions

When creating a model, say for products you'll be listing on an eBay-like site, what are the naming conventions for models and controllers? Would the model be signular product.rb and the controller plural products_controller.rb?

Answer (score 3):

The convention is to use plural for controllers, and singular for models.

- Controller: `ProductsController` in file products_controller.rb
- Model: `Product` in file product.rb

Sources:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#controller-naming-convention
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#convention-over-configuration-in-active-record

Answer (score 2):

You're correct, singular model name, plural controller name. The full naming convention documentation is here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions